# How to set the daily quota and bandwidth control for all IP in DDWRT

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, dd-wrt

What I want to do with my DDWRT router is, I need to set the bandwidth control limit for all IP address to 1024kbps internet speed. Also I need to set the usage permission to 2GB quota per day, once it reach the limit it will reduce the speed or it will stop the service. In the meantime I only can see the special DDWRT version set the usage.